# Javascript slider not sliding, how to tell if there is a JS conflict?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have an existing website that the image slider no longer performs its slideshow function or slide arrow no longer advance the slideshow.  I'm assuming another script is causing this one to malfunction.  Can anyone tell me how or take a look and tell me where the problem is from a browser by chance?

URL:

Comment: you can see at the Mozilla browser using the tool "net" in firebug.

Comment: @HarshalMahajan It would be **Console** tab.

Comment: Did you include JS files. as well as piece of code for invoking the slider?. If you want to check Jquery conflict issue you can check Console tab in FF browser.

Comment: First of all try to fix all broken tag in your page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Answer (score 1):

I have faced similar problem. but since we added the noConflict, this code needs to change... change the "$" into "jQuery" to fix that one error.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider .scroll').slide(1, 10000);
});
```

change to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#slider .scroll').slide(1, 10000);
});
```